# Ajax + js (without jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a trouble with IE. This code isn't working in IE, but in others it works well. I found that IE isn't working with jQuery AJAX, so its need to be without. Maybe somebody knows about this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.randomuser.me/?results=11',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (result, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            console.log(result);
            //alert(result);
            var event = JSON.parse(result);
            var our_html = "<table 'border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
            our_html += "<tr><th style='width:52px;border-left:none;'>№</th><th>Имя Фамилия Отчество</th><th>Адрес</th><th>Фото</th><th style='width:180px;border-right: none;'>Действие</th></tr>";
            event.results.forEach(function (item, item_number) {
                var u = item.user;
                our_html += "<tr>";
                our_html += "<td style='width:52px;'>" + (parseInt(item_number) + 1) + "</td>";
                our_html += "<td class='usname'>" + u.name.title + "." + "<span>" + u.name.first + "</span>" + " " + "<span>" + u.name.last + "</span>" + "</td>";
                our_html += "<td class='usst'>" + "<span>" + u.location.city + "</span>" + ", " + u.location.street + "</td>";

                our_html += '<td style="width:146px;"><img style="max-width:60px; max-height:60px;border-radius: 30px;" src="' + u.picture.medium + '"></td>';
                our_html += '<td style="width:180px; border-right: solid 1px #e1e1e1;"><div class="more" onclick="alert("' + u.name.first + '")">Просмотреть</div></td>';
                our_html += "</tr>";
            });
            our_html += "</table>";

            document.getElementById("table-wrapper").innerHTML = our_html;
            //alert (event.results[0].user.name.title);  // Goper
            //$(".simple p").text(event.results[0].user.name.title);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: jQuery AJAX works fine in IE.  What problem are you having? What versions of jQuery and IE?

Comment: "Without jquery" and `$(document).ready(function () { $.ajax({` ? What version of IE? 6 and 11 are a little bit different to deal with.

Comment: jQuery AJAX works fine in IE. What version of IE and jQuery are you using? jQuery 2.0+ removed support for older IE browsers, so you may need to downgrade to 1.11

Comment: i have IE 11 guys. So it isnt works. I tried differents kinds of version jquery. 1.8 -2.2 .

Comment: "This code isn't working in IE" <---in what manner?  What results are you getting (or none at all)?

Comment: nothing..but when i put in error before sucess , like this

error: function(obj)
        {
            var s = "";
            for (prop in obj) {
             if (typeof obj[prop] != "function") {
                 s += "obj[" + prop + "] = " + obj[prop] + "; ";
             }
            }
            console.log(s);
        },

Comment: it sending me in console that : obj[readyState] = 0; obj[status] = 0; obj[statusText] = No Transport;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution without jQuery that supports IE8+:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://api.randomuser.me/?results=11', true);

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
      var resp = this.responseText;
      var yourEvent = JSON.parse(resp);
      //Do whatever you want with the yourEvent variable
    } else {
      //Debug error here!
      console.error("An error occurred");
    }
  }
};

request.send();
request = null;
```

Best regards,

Comment: i saw it before..so tried many times , really..can u show me with TeamViewer? Mbe i do something wrong

Comment: it isn't working in IE. In others is good, in IE console SCRIPT5009: "JSON" undefined

Comment: Oh, that's a known issue. You can replace the `JSON.parse` with this library: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: which one? just only json.js ?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH MAN! U r really helped me with that. Broo) Write your wmz , i'll give u some )

Comment: There's no need to. But my PayPal, if you have, is on my SE profile page :)

Comment: By the way, could you add an up vote, too? SE Reputation matters to me a lot :)

Comment: when i can, i will. it's need to 15 rep for do this

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery, you should use that instead of vanilla DOM scripting.

Instead of

```
document.getElementById("table-wrapper").innerHTML=our_html;
```

try using:

```
$('#table-wrapper').html(our_html);
```

Works here: http://jsbin.com/zoyinoguri/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Since you are using IE11, I just tested it. As you can see, it works in IE11: http://gyazo.com/ac737852f107595e1ac0ddd3f88a4c21

Comment: ths guy. so my code is good? Really? just put 
$('#table-wrapper').html(our_html);    instead of mine?

Comment: funny..it isn't works like that ...I'm working on the Open Server , local server. so , i have a page , it isn't working.. Url that u shown to me , it isnt works like that

Comment: Yes, did you try that?

Comment: y, i do. so if i show u in skype, u will understand what i mean, can u give skype pls? My  svitoi41